# Как спарсить результат внешней работы внутреннего скрипта callback функции?

Tags: javascript, json, vkontakte-api, api

объясните пожалуйста начинающему, как спарсить результат внешнего Script'a ? Или как можно сделать аналогично данному скрипту.
В консоли данный скрипт отрабатывает на все 100% но как заставить его работать на сайте ума не приложу. Суть в том что бы выгрузить количество подписчиков из ВК на сайт.

````
  let script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
  script.src = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_id=85050907&fields=members_count&v=5.80&access_token=************************************&callback=callbackFunc";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  function callbackFunc(result) {
    $('#vkontakte_count').text(result.response[0].members_count)
  }
});```
````

Comment: Вот смотрю на якобы скрипт, а мне кажется что это запрос к API в контакте. Который вызывается через fetch и обрабатывается  в then()

Comment: @AzizUmarov Через Fetch уже делал запрос вот такого плана. Но ошибка будет в другом "Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»" и данный запрос не сработает, а отсутствует он именно на сервере VK.  $(document).ready(function () {
var baseUrL = 'https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_id=85050907..';
fetch(baseUrL).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {
if (res.error == 200) {
console.log('lol');
$('#vkontakte_count').text(res.data.response.members_count);
}
}).catch((error) => {
console.log(error)
})
});

Comment: Обрабатывайте запрос к api у себя сервере либо добавьте заголовки в запрос fetch {headers:{....}}

Comment: Правильно ли я вас понимаю, что мне нужно сделать запрос из PHP файла и после полученный ответ спарсить?

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете

Comment: Ох боже за PHP не шарю совсем(((

Comment: Напишите на чём Шарите и отправьте запрос через него :)))

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо сделать http запрос к апи и вы сможете получить результат. Смотрите что такое http запросы, ajax, и документацию к апи вк

Comment: Если вы про запрос типа https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest то данный запрос выдаст ошибку "Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_id=850... (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»)."

Comment: Смотрите документацию к апи, значит что то вы в header не передаете. Покажите код запроса

Comment: Это и есть весь код запроса, у меня вопрос как теперь спарсить ответ получаемый от этого запроса? Вот пример документации https://vk.com/dev/api_requests?f=4.1.%20Кроссдоменный%20запрос%20с%20использованием%20JSONP